# Huggingface transformers trainer output not giving any predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

After running a huggingface transformers trainer and training the model, I called the predict function with a tokenized evaluation dataset. The problem is there is no output for the predictions. Specifically, this is what I am getting:

PredictionOutput(predictions=None, label_ids=None, metrics={'test_loss': 0.5843013525009155, 'test_runtime': 13.1022, 'test_samples_per_second': 7.632, 'test_steps_per_second': 0.153})

I tried remaking my tokenized evaluation dataset and even used different column names, but every time the result is the same. I am expecting the usual output with prediction probabilities.

Comment: hey, can you share more details on your code here?